# Deleting an array of data with breeze

Tags: arrays, angularjs, entity, breeze

I have an array of data called vm.items, each position contains a row from my sql server database of data.

I want to be able to delete 1 element from the array and save changes on the server at the click of a button.

I have two more buttons for add in database and save .... and these are the functions for them.

```
vm.newItem = function () {
            var item = datacontext.manager.createEntity('Persoana', { idStrada: 2, nume: 'test', prenume: 'test' });
            vm.items.push(item);
        }

        vm.save = function () {
            datacontext.manager.saveChanges(datacontext.manager.getChanges()).then(
                function (data){alert(data);},
                function (error){alert(error);});
        }
```

First I click add, and then I click save.

I would like to do the same thing with delete... delete 1 row and than press save. If is not possible ... delete and save in the same function. I don't know how to do it. Any thoughts?
so far this is all i got...

```
vm.delete = function{};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but if you already have the entity that you want to delete then simply call

```
myEntity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
datacontext.manager.saveChanges([myEntity]).then(
        function (data){alert(data);},
        function (error){alert(error);})
```

Comment: well..i kind of have an array of entities... i get the results from database in vm.items . how can i delete from array? im new at js/breeze.. and im not very familiar with this.

Comment: vm.delete = function () {
            vm.items.entityAspect.setDeleted();
            datacontext.manager.saveChanges([vm.items]).then(
                    function (data) { alert(data); },
                    function (error) { alert(error); }) }                   if i try this i get an error "unable to get property of 'setdeleted' of undefined or null reference" . vm.delete is the function i call from the html.

Comment: 'entityAspect' is a per entity property, you would need to do items.forEach(function(item) { item.entityAspect.setDeleted(); });

Comment: hmm..but i can't use items.forEach.. because my items are inside vm container. So ..if i try to use vm.delete = function () {
            vm.items.forEach(function (item) {
                item.entityAspect.setDeleted();
            });

            datacontext.manager.saveChanges([item]).then(
        function (data) { alert(data); },
        function (error) { alert(error); }) } ..i get the error "unable to get property 'setDeleted'  for undefined reference"

Comment: also hand over the entity using vm.delete(vm.myEntity) and then use the code proposed by jay

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Deleting was working... but they were no entities to delete. At query i needed to "cast" the result as my datatype. There is a method in breeze called toType();

Answer (score -1):

When I encountered this problem, I resolved it with a for loop starting from the end to the beginning of the array.